# Drupal: Subtitles in views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8, drupal-taxonomy

I made a product content type with following fields: Name, price, categorie (taxonomy)

I then used views to make a simple pricelist.

- White bread
- Brown bread
- Chocolate cake
- Strawberry pie

The bread has "Bread" as categorie, the chocolate cake and strawberry pie have "pie" as categorie. I ordened the product list using this category so that all the bread and all the pie are together. What I want to do now is having a subtitle with the categorie everytime a new categorie begins.

Like this

**Bread**

- White Bread € 2.50
- Brown Bread € 2.70

**Cake**

- Chocolate cake € 7.00
- Strawberry cake € 10.00

I can't seem to find anywhere how to do that easily.

Any of you guys have an idea? Is there a way to do this withouth needing tot make my own module?

Answer (score 0):

I just found it myself after some logic thinking. I am going to post the answer here if anyone should need this.

I added category (taxonomy) to my fields and excluded it from display.

Then I went to settings next to grid and used Categorie for Grouping nr. 1